# What is the best way to test interface of a command line application with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, testing

Say that I have simple command line application, that looks something like this

```
# solution.rb

puts "Enter your password:"
password = gets

if password == "secret"
  puts "you're logged in"
else
  puts "wrong password"
end
```

and I need to create a script, that will test if it works correctly. I don't want to test the code itself, only it's user interface.

It would be a kind of homework checker, where a user can submit a script which is supposed to handle a certain task in a certain way, and this script will test it with given inputs.

The idea is, that I would run something like

```
ruby tester.rb solution.rb
```

and the `tester.rb` would first run it and pass `secret` and check if it got `you're logged in` as a response, and the same thing for the second case.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend you check out [cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber) with [aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba), which is specifically designed for this sort of thing.

There's a [quick intro](http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/04/22/aruba---cucumber-goodness-for-the-command-line/) which might be a good place to start.

Comment: I'd +1 again if I could for your avatar (on top of it being the same answer I was going to give :P).